# How to put a delay on <Switch> upon clicking on link for CSS-Transition exit animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have  within my  and it's performing the animations properly with CSSTransitions. However, the Switch is cancelling out the exit, and exit-active animations and it goes straight to doing the enter animation. Is it possible to set a delay on Switch to allow for the exit animation to finish?

I manually tried entering exit and exit-active, and it performs the animation fine.

But when a link is clicked, instead of:

```
<div class="exit and exit-active">
```

running, what it does is Switch automatically puts enter on top, negating the exit animation and it just goes straight to the enter animation

```
<div class="page slide-enter-done">
<div class="exit and exit-active">
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import './aboutme.css';
import AboutMe from './Projects';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import {
  CSSTransition,
  TransitionGroup,
} from 'react-transition-group';
// class component
class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="nav">
          <NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="active">About 
           Me</NavLink>
    </div>
    <Route render={({location}) => (
      <TransitionGroup>
        <CSSTransition 
          key={location.key}
          timeout={{enter: 300, exit: 400 }}
          classNames="slide"
        >
    <Switch location={location}>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
    </CSSTransition>
    </TransitionGroup>
      )} />

  </div>
);
  }
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
.slide-enter {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-100vw, 0, 0);
  color: transparent;
  background-color: #5a564c;
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

}
.slide-enter-active {
background-color: #9e8949;
transition: all 300ms;
transform: translate3d(0vw, 0, 0);
}

.slide-exit {
  background-color: #9e8949;
  transition: all 400ms;
  transform: translate3d(0vw, 0, 0);
}

.slide-exit-active {
transform: translate3d(100vw, 0, 0);
transition: all 300ms;
}
```

I want a way to show the exit-animation, but whenever a link is clicked, it "covers" the exit animation and goes straight to the enter animation

Answer (score 0):

react-transition-group is a very old approach to animation with react, react-spring is a more modern more complete (but light weight) library.

I know this doesn't fully answer your question but i would suggest using react-spring and doing something like this to transition between routes.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/jp1wr1867w

There are many reasons why spring-based animation feels better for users, alot of which you can read about on their website; however just not having to hard code duration's is always a bonus.